# EditText no show text

Tags: android, user-interface

I´m trying show text on a EditText, but no show anythigs, the code is this:

```
public void run() 
{
    String mensaje;
    while(true)
    {
      try 
      {
        mensaje = b.readLine();
        Log.d("mensaje", mensaje);
       _et_ip.setText(mensaje);
      } 
      catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }
 }
```

The main class implements runnable

```
public class ClienteTcpAnroid extends Activity implements Runnable
```

and Log.d show the message correct but  _et_ip.setText(mensaje) no show the message.

I´m using android emulator

Thanks you very much

This is all code:

```
public class ClienteTcpAnroid extends Activity implements Runnable
{

private static  String myIP;
private static String myPort;
String mensaje;
Thread threadProcesaAlarmas;
public TextView _tv_estado;
    public EditText _et_ip;
    public EditText _et_port;
    public Button botonConectar;
    BufferedReader b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _tv_estado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_estado);
        _et_ip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
        _et_port = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_port);
        botonConectar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        botonConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {            
         public void onClick(View v)
             { 
                Socket mySocket;
            PrintStream p;
            try 
            {
                mySocket = new Socket("192.168.1.35", 12345);
    b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream()));
                threadProcesaAlarmas = new Thread(ClienteTcpAnroid.this);
                threadProcesaAlarmas.start();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    String mensaje;
    while(true)
    {
        try 
        {
            mensaje = b.readLine();
            Log.d("mensaje", mensaje);
            _et_ip.setText(mensaje);
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Thanks you very much

This is log:

```
11-03 20:01:08.507: D/mensaje(957): mensaje0  
11-03 20:01:08.507: W/dalvikvm(957): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):   android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:642)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:668)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5255)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:3683)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:6390)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:6515)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:906)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:611)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:514)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:74)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:85)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:268)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2712)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at packag.Android.ClienteTcpAnroid.run(ClienteTcpAnroid.java:80)
11-03 20:01:08.536: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-03 20:01:08.566: W/ActivityManager(77):   Force finishing activity packag.Android/.ClienteTcpAnroid
11-03 20:01:08.767: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(957): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Thanks kevin

Comment: I can guess the main thread cannot respond due your infinite loop. ANR might be thrown as well. Check `traces.txt` (in your DDMS file explorer)

Comment: what do you want to implement exactly?

Comment: I want read messages the a TCP conection and show it on EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  Issue #1, you're eating your Exceptions.  I'm pretty sure (although maybe its changed?) e.printStackTrace() does nothing.  You either need to log them with Log, or wrap and throw with RuntimeException (I prefer to fail than quietly ignore, so I chose the latter).

You have 2 ways of doing this (well, several, but we'll discuss 2).

1) Do the background stuff in an AsyncTask.  I'd pick that.  Much easier than creating/managing your own thread.

2) Keep your code, but when you update the UI, do it with a Handler that was created in the UI thread.

```
public class ClienteTcpAnroid extends Activity implements Runnable
{

    private static String myIP;
    private static String myPort;
    String mensaje;
    Thread threadProcesaAlarmas;
    public TextView _tv_estado;
    public EditText _et_ip;
    public EditText _et_port;
    public Button botonConectar;
    BufferedReader b;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _tv_estado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_estado);
        _et_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
        _et_port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_port);
        botonConectar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        botonConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Socket mySocket;
                PrintStream p;
                try
                {
                    mySocket = new Socket("192.168.1.35", 12345);
                    b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream()));
                    threadProcesaAlarmas = new Thread(ClienteTcpAnroid.this);
                    threadProcesaAlarmas.start();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                final String mensaje = b.readLine();
                Log.d("mensaje", mensaje);
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        _et_ip.setText(mensaje);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I assume the socket read is blocking.  You have an "infinite loop", of course, but that's not a big deal since it blocks.  The only thing I'd suggest is figuring how to cut that off in onPause.

Also BTW, forget AsyncTask here.  Didn't realize the exact thing you were trying to do till just now.  Thread is the way to go.  Well, I think a Service is the way to go, but this will work.

Comment: Thank you very much by suggestion kevin, but no work, the Log show:                                                               11-03 18:47:06.077: W/dalvikvm(873): 11-03 18:47:06.037:  D/mensaje(873): mensaje0
threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

Comment: Please post full logcat logs.  There's no error info in your comment.  If data is coming over your connection properly, that code should work.  Something else is (probably) failing.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, work fine, i have created a nes emulator and all ok, Thanks